# About the conditions of a theorem involving moment generating functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

According to the book "Mathematical Statistics" written by Wiebe R. Pestman, we have the following theorem:

> Let $X$ be a random variable and $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence
> of random variables. Suppose the moment generating functions $M_X$ and
> $M_{X_n}$ exists (for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$) on a common interval
> $(-\infty ,\xi ]$ and suppose that
> $\lim_{n\to\infty}M_{X_n}(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}M_X(t)$ for all $t\in(-\infty,\xi ]$. Then the sequence $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges
> in distribution to $X$.

**My question is:** Is it really necessary for both $M_X(t)$ and $M_{X_n}(t)$ to be finite in the interval $(-\infty,\xi]$?

---

The book I mentioned doesn't provide a proof of the previous theorem. So, could please provide a reference that contains a proof of that theorem?

The book I mentioned provides a reference, but I don't have access to it.

---

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: 1. What is that reference?  2.  It is sufficient that the existence and convergence of the mgfs occur on any a open interval $(a,b)$ where $a<b$.  3. Do you know Lévy's continuity theorem? Or: what proofs for convergence in distribution are you comfortable with?

Comment: The issue is that there are multiple distributions $X$ can have such that $M_X(t) = \infty$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.  If $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables with different distributions that both have infinite moment generating functions for all $t$, then the constant sequence $X_n = Y$ would satisfy $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} M_{X_n}(t) = M_X(t)$, but $X_n$ wouldn't converge to $X$ in distribution.